# Angularjs populating dropdown with in ng-repeat from different scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following controller which gets data from database using factory which works fine.

My service is

```
App.factory("pOvRepository", ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return {

        pw: $resource('/api/pOv/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } }),
        ps: $resource('/api/pStatus/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } })
    };

}]);
```

Controller is

```
App.controller('pOvCtrl', function ($scope, pOvRepository,  $location) {
    $scope.poviews = pOvRepository.pw.query();
    $scope.pS = pOvRepository.ps.query();
```

The data I get for $scope.pS  is

```
    [{"p_status1":"Up Coming","p_id":1,"proj":[]},
{"p_status1":"In Progress","p_id":2,"proj":[]},
{"p_status1":"On Hold","p_id":3,"proj":[]}]
```

In my html code I am trying to populate the dropdown with data from $scope.pS

```
<div ng-controller="pOvCtrl">
 <form ng-repeat="p in poviews">
 <input type="text" ng-model="p.include_in"/>
<select ng-model="p.p_id" ng-options="a.p_status1 as a.p_id for a in pS"></select>
</form>
```

When I run it, the dropdown does not get populated with the options from $scope.pS
Please let me know how I can fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing your service, you need to specify a callback for the data:

```
pOvRepository.ps.query({}, function(data) {
    $scope.pS = data;
});
```

Comment: I didnt add the service because I am receiving the data back fine from it. I can see it in firebug.

Comment: @J.Davidson -- I know that, you just don't assign it right. Post the service.

Comment: just added service in the post. Thanks

Comment: Got it thanks. I am kind of new to angular world. Can you let me know why it needed to be assigned with callback? Thanks

Comment: According to the docs you get an empty reference at first until the call returns (which no doubt yours is doing). So that's not it. I'm thinking it is related to you not following the scope golden rule.